# AngularJS display list right below the URL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I am trying to display a list of values on the front end right below where they are clicked. For instance, lets say my front end has a list of albums:

```
album-name-1
album-name-2
album-name-3
```

When I click album-name-1 I need the tracks of album-name-1 to be displayed right below album-name-1. When I click album-name 2, I don't want to see album-name-1 to be shown and only display the tracks for album-name-2 below album-name-2 and so on. Like the following:

```
album-name-1
   - track1
   - track2
   - track3
album-name-2
album-name-3
```

or when I click album-name-2:

```
album-name-1
album-name-2
   - track1
   - track2
   - track3
album-name-3
```

Right now, with my code, when I click any album, it displays the tracks below every album even if they don't belong to that album like:

```
album-name-1
   - track1
   - track2
   - track3
album-name-2
   - track1
   - track2
   - track3
album-name-3
   - track1
   - track2
   - track3
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
hello!
<div>
    <ul  ng-repeat="album in vm.albums">
        <li><a ng-click="vm.getAlbumTracks(album)">{{album}}</a></li>
        <ul ng-repeat="track in vm.albums.tracks">
            <li><a ng-click="vm.displayForm(track)">{{track}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <a ng-click="vm.newFunction('RAVI')">Click Me!</a>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
FileUploadFormController.$inject = ['$http', '$log', '$scope', '$rootScope', 'APP_CONFIG'];
function FileUploadFormController ($http, $log, $scope, $rootScope, APP_CONFIG){

var vm = this;
vm.albums = init;
vm.albums.tracks = getAlbumTracks;
vm.newFunction = newFunction;

return init();
function init(){
 $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/albums').then(function(responseData){
        // Parse the json data here and display it in the UI
        $scope.vm.albums = responseData.data;
        $log.debug(angular.toJson(responseData, true));

//              console.log(vm.albums.tracks);
        return vm.albums;
    })
}

function getAlbumTracks(album, $scope){
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/albums/'+album).success(function(trackResponse){
        //parse each album and get the track list
        $scope.vm.albums.tracks = vm.albums.tracks.concat(trackResponse);
        return vm.albums.tracks;
    })
}

}
```

Any clue how to achieve that ?

Comment: I want to use ng-hide or ng-show when I click on album1, hide other ones or only show album1. But not sure how

Comment: Can you Provide a Plnkr ? with sample reponse json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have markup like this

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="album in vm.albums">
        <a ng-click="vm.getAlbumTracks(album, $index);">{{album}}</a>
        <ul ng-show="$index === vm.showingAlbumIndex">
            <li ng-repeat="track in vm.albums.tracks"><a ng-click="vm.displayForm(track)">{{track}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<a ng-click="vm.newFunction('RAVI')">Click Me!</a>
```

In function controller, assign property `vm.showingAlbumIndex`

```
function getAlbumTracks(album, index){
    vm.showingAlbumIndex = index;
    //...
}
```