# Angular Footable to show selected column data only

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I was wondering if there is a way in Footable to show only the data colmuns for the one you have selected and hide the others.

For example, let's say the below are the list of albums (rows in my footable)

```
album-name-1
album-name-2
album-name-3
```

And if I select the album 1, it's data appears as follows:

```
album-name-1

track1
track2
track3
album-name-2
album-name-3
```

If I select album2, only those details appear and the previously expanded tracks from album 1 get collapsed as follows:

```
album-name-1
album-name-2

track1
track2
track3
album-name-3
```

I am using angularJS to use footable. Any suggestions on how to achieve this ? Like I know if I didn't use fancy stuff like Footable, I can achieve this by trigerring a click event using ng-click and pass on the index to show/hide only what I need. Just as this answer I asked previously: [AngularJS display list right below the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664368/angularjs-display-list-right-below-the-url)

But here, I am trying to do with the Footable plugin. Here is my html snippet for the same:

```
<table class="footable table table-stripped toggle-arrow-tiny" data-page-size="8">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-toggle="all">Release Title</th>
                        <th data-toggle="all">Release Genre</th>
                        <th data-toggle="all">Classical</th>
                        <th data-hide="all">Tracks</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="album in vm.albums" footable>
                        <td ng-click="vm.editAlbum(album, $index)">{{album.data.title}}</small></td>
                        <td>{{album.data.genre}}</td>
                        <td ng-if!="album.data.classical">No</td>
                        <td ng-if="album.data.classical">Yes</td>
                        <td><br>
                            <li ng-repeat="track in album.data.tracks">
                                <a ng-click="vm.selectTrack(album, track)">{{track.title}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <ul class="pagination pull-right"></ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>
</table>
```